# Implementing a tabular within a forest node produces two bracket failures

Tags: tables, tikz-trees, forest, tikz-qtree

i'm currently using the forest-usepackage in order to build up a family tree. I'd like to implement a table within a forest node. As long as i don't hit the 100 failure mark the code will be compiled and everything looks fine.

My Question: How to get rid of my bracket failures?

I got an minimized example right below.

```
\documentclass[margin=1cm]{standalone}
%
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[edges,linguistics]{forest}
\usepackage{textcomp}
%
\begin{document}
%
\begin{forest}
  for tree=
    {
     draw,
     minimum height=3cm,
     minimum width=3cm,
     l sep+=2cm,
     edge path={\noexpand\path[\forestoption{edge}] (\forestOve{\forestove{@parent}}{name}.parent anchor) -- +(0,-1cm)-| (\forestove{name}.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};}
    }
    [{\begin{tabular}{ll}{Stephanus & \\ ... & ... \\ abc & äöü}\end{tabular}}
       [Christina]
       [Maria]
       [Stephanus]
     ]
\end{forest}
%
\end{document}
```

The only messages that are shown are:

```
Error line 25 !Missing }inserted.<inserted text>}\end{forest}

Error line 25 !Missing {inserted.<inserted text>{\end{forest}

"I've put in what seems to be necessary to fix
the current column of the current alignment.
Try to go on, since this might almost work."
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Placing the contents of the `tabular` environment in braces appears to be to blame (I'm not entirely clear why) `\begin{tabular}{ll} Stephanus & \\ ... & ... \\ abc & äöü \end{tabular}` compiles without error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you will drop curly braces (the cause of your troubles are inner ones) in table, than your problem will disappear:

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[edges,linguistics]{forest}
%\usepackage{textcomp}

\begin{document}
%
\begin{forest}
  for tree = {draw,
     minimum height = 2cm, % <-- changed
      minimum width = 3cm,
               font = \linespread{.9}\selectfont, %< -- added for less vertical space between lines in nodes
              l sep = 12mm,
       forked edge,       % <-- added
          fork sep = 6mm  % <-- added
             }
    [ \begin{tabular}{r@{\hskip=6pt}l} %<-- changed tabcolsep
       Stephanus & Cornellus  \\ 
           ??    & 1234       \\ 
             abc & defghijk
      \end{tabular}% <-- here I remove surplus braces
       [Christina]
       [Maria]
       [Stephanus]
     ]
\end{forest}
%
\end{document}
```

**Edit:** small changes (deleting of `edge path = {...}` is stolen from @cfr answer), which to my taste make tree more beautiful :). All are designated in above code.

Comment: It wasn''t the braces around the `tabular` that were the problem, but rather the braces around the content of the `tabular`! (These: `{Stephanus & \\ ... & ... \\ abc & äöü}`.)

Comment: yes, the cause  were  inner braces. but after their removing I see, that also work without outer too. probably they should be returned for cases  (I suppose), when in tabular are`[ ` `]`.

Comment: This may work, but you could just use `align`, which seems simpler to me. And the `edges` library is not doing much here. ;)

Answer (score 3):

When you specify `align` in Forest, you are actually giving a tabular specification. Hence, your code attempts to nest a tabular within a tabular, which is not really necessary and will probably just create unwanted space.

Also, you don't appear to be using the `edges` library, despite loading it, but are instead emulating its `forked edges` style. It would be easier to use the pre-defined style and just adjust the distance between the parent and the fork.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[edges,linguistics]{forest}
\usepackage{textcomp}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
  forked edges,
  for tree={
    draw,
    fork sep'=1cm,
    minimum height=3cm,
    minimum width=3cm,
    l sep+=2cm,
  }
  [Stephanus & \\ ... & ... \\ abc & äöü, align={ll}
     [Christina]
     [Maria]
     [Stephanus]
   ]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

[image: tabular in tree with forked edges]

## EDIT

If you want to specify a different inter-column spacing for the tabular, you cannot write

```
align={l@{\hskip <dimension>}l}
```

as this upsets Forest's parser.

However, you can do one of two things.

First, if you want to change the spacing between two columns, you can load the `array` package and create a new column type. For a left-aligned column followed by variable column spacing,

```
\newcolumntype{k}[1]{l@{\hskip #1}}
```

allows you to write

```
align={k{2.5pt}l}
```

If you want to alter the inter-column spacing for all tabulars in the tree, you can simply execute the relevant TeX code. For example,

```
TeX={\setlength{\tabcolsep}{10pt}}
```

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[edges,linguistics]{forest}
\usepackage{textcomp,array}
\newcolumntype{k}[1]{l@{\hskip #1}}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  forked edges,
  for tree={
    draw,
    fork sep'=1cm,
    minimum height=3cm,
    minimum width=3cm,
    l sep+=2cm,
  }
  [\multicolumn{2}{l}{Stephanus}  \\ ... & ... \\ abc & äöü, align={ll}
     [Christina]
     [Maria]
     [Stephanus]
   ]
\end{forest}
\begin{forest}
  forked edges,
  for tree={
    draw,
    fork sep'=1cm,
    minimum height=3cm,
    minimum width=3cm,
    l sep+=2cm,
  }
  [\multicolumn{2}{l}{Stephanus}  \\ ... & ... \\ abc & äöü, align={k{2.5pt}l}
     [Christina]
     [Maria]
     [Stephanus]
   ]
\end{forest}
\begin{forest}
  forked edges,
  TeX={\setlength{\tabcolsep}{10pt}},
  for tree={
    draw,
    fork sep'=1cm,
    minimum height=3cm,
    minimum width=3cm,
    l sep+=2cm,
  }
  [\multicolumn{2}{l}{Stephanus}  \\ ... & ... \\ abc & äöü, align={ll}
     [Christina]
     [Maria]
     [Stephanus]
   ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

demonstrates the effects:

[image: spacing variations]

Comment: good solution! I was not aware for `align={...}` option. now I wonder, if it is possible to change `tabcolsep` inside `forest` environment or is only solution to encapsulate `forest` in group, where before `forest` is defined `tabcolsep`?

Comment: @Zarko I'm sure you can do it. Here, I'd just specify the dimension directly if I wanted it to be different e.g. `l@{1pt}l` or whatever as that seems simpler.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work. It print out `1pt`. Do I miss something?  Reading of `forest` documentation doesn't help me much, I find only example how to write a table with `forest` (page 38), but example is so complicated (I still not figured out, how it works) that to my opinion is simpler to use standard table in node.

Comment: @Zarko Hmm. Yes. The usual `@{\hskip 1pt}` does not seem to work ...

Comment: well, than my answer solve this (since use standard tabular), but this was not OP concern :)

Comment: @Zarko Please see edit above.

Comment: Amazing! To me is the most important solution with `TeX={\setlength{\tabcolsep}{10pt}},`. So far I didn't see this option in `forest` manual. Now I see, that didn't read it enough carefully :(.